# ¿Cómo hacer que cambie la propiedad top de un elemento cuando cambio el ancho de la ventana del navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día.

Tengo un `div class="cabeceraLogo">` en el siguiente `<div class="cabeceraCentral>` que contiene un párrafo y luego otro en el div siguiente tengo otro `div class="cabeceraOpc">` que tiene otros elementos como íconos y una lista (menú); mediante javascript y con jquery estoy obteniendo las alturas externas de las respectivas divisiones para que en una variable poder sumar estas alturas para darle un tope a la lista.

```
$(window).change(function() {
   var tp = $(window).width();
   var cLogo = $('.cabeceraLogo').outerHeight(true);
   var cCentral = $('.cabeceraCentral').outerHeight(true);
   var cMenu = $('.cabeceraOpc').outerHeight(true);
   var cabecera = cLogo + cCentral + cMenu;
   if (tp < 387) {
      $('.menu').css('top', cabecera + 'px');
   } else {
      $('.menu').css('top', cabecera + 'px');
   }
});
```

esto lo quiero hacer dinámico ya que con el navegador tengo la posibilidad de ir modificando el ancho de la ventana que se visualiza y por ese motivo es que pongo en la condicional `tp < 387` que es el ancho en que ya el párrafo cambia su alto. He intentado poniendo las líneas anteriores adentro de  `$(window).change(function() { ... }` pero obviamente no funcionó ya que en la documentación de `.change()` sale que funciona con otros elementos como por ejemplo `<div>`, luego sustituí  por `$('.cabeceraCentral').change(function() { ... }` esperando que sea dinámico  el comportamiento y de igual manera no funcionó.

**¿Talvez alguien tiene una idea sobre cómo se puede hacer dinámico los cambios?**

Comment: El evento para detectar cambios en el tamaño de la ventana no es `change` sino `resize` y es conveniente aplicarlo de la forma adecuada: `$(window).on('resize', function() { /* Aquí el código de tu función */ });`

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Triby; ya lo voy a intentar